# Category Header Widget

Tags: category, header, widget

I hope this is the right category and someone can help point me in the right direction. I created an instance of a widget and have a static block associated to it. I have it placed to appear in the Category header. However, it is placed below the description and i would like to have up more and place it between the title and description of the category. Where or how can I control the exact placement of this widget inside of the category header? Please attachment. Thanks in advance.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The static block is rendered in the template file `catalog/category/view.phtml`. If you wish this to appear above the title you will need to copy the file to your theme from `app/design/frontend/base/default/` and modify it to more like this:

```
<?php if($this->isContentMode() || $this->isMixedMode()): ?>
    <?php echo $this->getCmsBlockHtml() ?>
<?php endif ?>

<?php if($_imgUrl): ?>
    <?php echo $_imgHtml ?>
<?php endif; ?>

<?php if($_description=$this->getCurrentCategory()->getDescription()): ?>
    <div class="category-description std">
        <?php echo $_helper->categoryAttribute($_category, $_description, 'description') ?>
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>

<?php if ( ! $this->isContentMode()): ?>
    <?php echo $this->getProductListHtml() ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: I tried something similar to this before and it didn't work. I also tried this suggestion as well with no luck. thank you for replying.